# Docker ignores ENTRYPOINT

Tags: docker, etcd

There are some weird errors running the following docker command:

```
docker run -d \
    --network="etcd" \
    --ip 172.28.0.4 \
    -v $(pwd)/etcd01:/etc/ssl/certs \
    -p 4001:4001 -p 2380:2380 -p 2379:2379 \
    --hostname etcd01 \
    --name etcd01 quay.io/coreos/etcd:latest \
    -name etcd01 \
    -advertise-client-urls http://172.28.0.4:2379,http://172.28.0.4:4001 \
    -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001 \
    -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://172.28.0.4:2380 \
    -listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380 \
    -initial-cluster etcd01=http://172.28.0.4:2380,etcd01=http://172.28.0.2:2380,etcd02=http://172.28.0.3:2380 \
    -initial-cluster-state new
```

There is an ENTRYPOINT defined in [etcd's Dockerfile](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Dockerfile#L6). And the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) say that everything after the image name is handed over as params to the entrypoint. Then why isn't it?

I get errors like: `docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"-name\": executable file not found in $PATH".`

Of course `-name` is not the command. It is supposed to be the first argument to `etcd`.

Comment: what happens if you add `--entrypoint=etcd` before quay.io?

Comment: Thanks, it probably uses the [other Dockerfile](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/blob/master/Dockerfile-release#L17) which doesn't contain an ENTRYPOINT. Haven't thought about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probelmas that are overwriting the command of the container. To perform this action I recommend that you modify your command a little:

```
docker run -d \
    --network="etcd" \
    --ip 172.28.0.4 \
    -v $(pwd)/etcd01:/etc/ssl/certs \
    -p 4001:4001 -p 2380:2380 -p 2379:2379 \
    --hostname etcd01 \
    --name etcd01 quay.io/coreos/etcd:latest \
    etcd \
    -name etcd01 \
    -advertise-client-urls http://172.28.0.4:2379,http://172.28.0.4:4001 \
    -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001 \
    -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://172.28.0.4:2380 \
    -listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380 \
    -initial-cluster etcd01=http://172.28.0.4:2380,etcd01=http://172.28.0.2:2380,etcd02=http://172.28.0.3:2380 \
    -initial-cluster-state new
```